# How do I repeat the form POST request programmatically

Tags: ruby, network-programming, http-post, charles-proxy

When I visit the site http://www.jetstar.com/au/en/home

And fill the form then submit.

[image]

It will send a **POST request** then redirect me to new page show the ticket price page(HTML).

I can get the expected result in the second **GET** response

[image]

However, When I try to repeat the POST request with **Ruby** or **Charles**

I will get **302 Found** error.

I don't get it.

## Ruby

```
q_prams = {  
   "ControlGroupSearchView$AvailabilitySearchInputSearchView$DropDownListFareTypes"   =>"I",
   "ControlGroupSearchView$AvailabilitySearchInputSearchView$DropDownListMarketDay1"   =>"9",
   ~~~
   "pageToken"   =>"sLkmnwXwAsY=",
   "ControlGroupSearchView$AvailabilitySearchInputSearchView$fromCS"   =>"yes"
}

res = RestClient.post 'https://booknow.jetstar.com/Search.aspx', q_prams
```

## POST request params

```
ControlGroupSearchView%24AvailabilitySearchInputSearchView%24DropDownListCurrency=&ControlGroupSearchView%24AvailabilitySearchInputSearchView%24DropDownListFareTypes=I&ControlGroupSearchView%24AvailabilitySearchInputSearchView%24DropDownListMarketDay1=18&ControlGroupSearchView%24AvailabilitySearchInputSearchView%24DropDownListMarketDay2=1&ControlGroupSearchView%24AvailabilitySearchInputSearchView%24DropDownListMarketDay3=&ControlGroupSearchView%24AvailabilitySearchInputSearchView%24DropDownListMarketMonth1=2015-6&ControlGroupSearchView%24AvailabilitySearchInputSearchView%24DropDownListMarketMonth2=1968-1&ControlGroupSearchView%24AvailabilitySearchInputSearchView%24DropDownListMarketMonth3=&ControlGroupSearchView%24AvailabilitySearchInputSearchView%24DropDownListPassengerType_ADT=1&ControlGroupSearchView%24AvailabilitySearchInputSearchView%24DropDownListPassengerType_CHD=0&ControlGroupSearchView%24AvailabilitySearchInputSearchView%24DropDownListPassengerType_INFANT=0&ControlGroupSearchView%24AvailabilitySearchInputSearchView%24RadioButtonMarketStructure=OneWay&ControlGroupSearchView%24AvailabilitySearchInputSearchView%24TextBoxMarketDestination1=MEL&ControlGroupSearchView%24AvailabilitySearchInputSearchView%24TextBoxMarketDestination2=&ControlGroupSearchView%24AvailabilitySearchInputSearchView%24TextBoxMarketDestination3=&ControlGroupSearchView%24AvailabilitySearchInputSearchView%24TextBoxMarketOrigin1=NAN&ControlGroupSearchView%24AvailabilitySearchInputSearchView%24TextBoxMarketOrigin2=&ControlGroupSearchView%24AvailabilitySearchInputSearchView%24TextBoxMarketOrigin3=&ControlGroupSearchView%24ButtonSubmit=&__VIEWSTATE=&culture=en-AU&date_picker=&go-booking=&pageToken=sLkmnwXwAsY%3D&ControlGroupSearchView%24AvailabilitySearchInputSearchView%24fromCS=yes&_pe_39b5379c652b_9df496572198=null&locale=en-AU
```

## The first time response (SUCCESS) but cat not repeat it programmatically

```
<!doctype html><!--paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/--><!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <html lang="en" class="no-js ie6"> <![endif]--><!--[if IE 7 ]>    <html lang="en" class="no-js ie7"> <![endif]--><!--[if IE 8 ]>    <html lang="en" class="no-js ie8"> <![endif]--><!--[if IE 9 ]>    <html lang="en" class="no-js ie9"> <![endif]--><!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--><html lang="en" class="no-js"><!--<![endif]--><!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<head class="SB">
  <META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <title>Jetstar Airways Cheap Flights, Low Fares all day everyday from the world's best Cheap Fare airline</title>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
  <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/ico">
  <link rel="SHORTCUT ICON" href="favicon.ico">
...
```

Comment: 302 isn't an error code, it is an HTTP redirect.  Where is the server redirecting you?  That might provide a clue.

Answer (score 1):

This is most probably because of the `CSRF verification`, Sites users CSRF to validate the request to make sure the form submission came from the same site.

In your case, you try to submit a form from a different source and hence the verification fails.

If you want to do the above, I recon to do a screen scraping by using a library like [capybara](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara)

read more about CSRF [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery)